# How to enable-flex to true scss in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the latest version of bootstrap with bower. I'm using gulp task to pipe it over to css. In my style.scss I'm running

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

All this is working file. I'm reading the documentation on how to enable flexbox here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

The documentation says: Open the _variables.scss file and find the $enable-flex variable. Does this mean that I need to go into bower_components/bootstrap/scss/ and find _variables.scss, and change it there?

My gulp I have bootstrap defined as ./bower_components/bootstrap/scss

How do I deal with this without overriding, everything, and more importantly, how do I enable flex properly? I'm just adding my gulp file here just in case it needs to be.

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
     sass = require('gulp-sass'),
     autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
     notify = require("gulp-notify"),
     bower = require('gulp-bower');

let config = {
    bootstrapDir: './bower_components/bootstrap',
    fontawesomeDir: './bower_components/font-awesome',
    publicDir: './public',
    bowerDir: './bower_components'
}

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    return bower()
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/fonts/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/assets/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [config.bootstrapDir + '/scss', config.fontawesomeDir + '/scss'],
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + '/assets/css'));
});

// Watch task
gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['bower', 'fonts', 'css']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked in my case was adding a _custom.scss and @import that before I imported bootstrap. Bootstrap does have a _custom.scss file for such overrides but when you update bootstrap with bower, you will loose those changes.

Answer (score 0):

They should have added the partial `_custom.scss` to `.gitignore`.
Check the comment in `_custom.scss` :

```
// Bootstrap overrides
//
// Copy variables from `_variables.scss` to this file to override default values
// without modifying source files.
```

The variable `$enable-flex` is defined in partial `_variables.scss`.

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L113
>   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_custom.scss
>   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/.gitignore